# Bug in GAE/DataNucleus?, won't save to Google AppEngine Datastore with JPA 2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

This detached entity won't save to the datastore after merge. I've tried dozens of tricks with no luck. Is the solution JDO or raw Datastore API? It just won't save, no matter how long I wait.

```
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    OnixUser s = admin.get(0);
    if (s.id == null) {
        em.persist(s);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    else {
        log.info("email:" + s.email + ", isAdmin:" + s.isAdmin + ", id:" + s.id + ", state:" + NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(s));
        OnixUser merged = em.merge(s);
        log.info("merged... email:" + merged.email + ", isAdmin:" + merged.isAdmin + ", id:" + merged.id + ", state:" + NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(merged));
        em.persist(merged);   //// TRIED WITH & WITHOUT PERSIST
        log.info("persisted... email:" + merged.email + ", isAdmin:" + merged.isAdmin + ", id:" + merged.id + ", state:" + NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(merged));
        em.flush();
        log.info("flushed... email:" + merged.email + ", isAdmin:" + merged.isAdmin + ", id:" + merged.id + ", state:" + NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(merged));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.refresh(merged);  
        /////// THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS isAdmin reverts back to 0.
        log.info("refreshed... email:" + merged.email + ", isAdmin:" + merged.isAdmin + ", id:" + merged.id + ", state:" + NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(merged));
    }
    em.close();
```

#### Log

```
Oct 16, 2013 10:25:10 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:4793870697103360, state:detached
Oct 16, 2013 10:25:10 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: merged... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:4793870697103360, state:persistent
Oct 16, 2013 10:25:10 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: persisted... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:4793870697103360, state:persistent
Oct 16, 2013 10:25:10 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: flushed... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:4793870697103360, state:persistent
Oct 16, 2013 10:25:10 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: refreshed... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:0, id:4793870697103360, state:persistent
```

#### Finest Log, war/WEB-INF/logging.properties

```
.level=FINEST
DataNucleus.level=FINEST


Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection <init>
FINE: Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@470d08b4
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection
FINE: Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@58de89bb for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e3ad48 in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@61478c16]
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:6394759627145216, state:detached
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser@636a0148" (id="com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser:6394759627145216") has a lifecycle change : "P_CLEAN"->"P_NONTRANS"
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: merged... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:6394759627145216, state:persistent
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: persisted... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:6394759627145216, state:persistent
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: flushed... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:1, id:6394759627145216, state:persistent
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1 managedConnectionPostClose
FINE: Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@58de89bb for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e3ad48 in factory=ConnectionFactory:tx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@61478c16]
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection <init>
FINE: Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@1c00f18e
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection
FINE: Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@1f2afff for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e3ad48 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@4949a70e]
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection
FINE: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@1f2afff for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e3ad48 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@4949a70e]
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.example.sdm.server.SDMServiceImpl setAdmin
INFO: refreshed... email:chloe@example.com, isAdmin:0, id:6394759627145216, state:persistent
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.state.LifeCycleState changeState
FINE: Object "com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser@636a0148" (id="com.example.sdm.shared.OnixUser:6394759627145216") has a lifecycle change : "P_NONTRANS"->"DETACHED_CLEAN"
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl closeAllConnections
FINE: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@1f2afff for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e3ad48 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@4949a70e] but owner object closing so closing connection
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1 managedConnectionPostClose
FINE: Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@1f2afff for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e3ad48 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@4949a70e]
Oct 17, 2013 12:36:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.AppEngineAuthentication$AppEngineUserRealm disassociate
FINE: Ignoring disassociate call for: chloe@example.com
```

#### Versions

datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar, appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.5.jar

Comment: if you were wanting to DEBUG an application you would configure the log to DEBUG level, that tells you what is going on, and without that you can't say something "hasn't saved". No idea what your "persist" call is about ... you just merged an object. PS, This is Google's code, not DataNucleus JPA - https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/

Comment: The "finest" log still is filtering out a lot of messages, you must have config set to only show particular loggers. Also the logger category is useful to print out since it tells you what type of operation is being performed. Focus on the merge operation, where that object came from, what is changed in it (you post nothing about it), and what happens in the log at that call (not interested in before it, or after commit). That GAE project I linked to has many many tests of attaching for JPA, all work. Suggest you review them